# Opening text file trouble

Tags: java, io

I tried reading a text file from a directory , but it wont open unless i import the text file into the src of my java project which is not what i want 
I want to read a text file that is from a certain directory

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;
public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        String path="C:/My documents/file.txt";
        File F=new File(path);

          try{
            FileInputStream ips=new FileInputStream(F);//ou InputStream
            InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);//
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);//lire les lignes
            String ligne[]=new String[7];

            for (int i=1;i<ligne.length;i++)
            {
                ligne[i]=br.readLine();
                        System.out.println(ligne[i]);
            }

        br.close();

            }
            catch(Exception e1){System.out.println("error");    }

    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you run that code?

Comment: Define "Won't open" ... what's the error?

Comment: change String path="C:/My documents/file.txt"; to String path="C:\\My documents\\file.txt";

Comment: it's solved , thanks to Joelio. I just have to change the make the path this way C:\\My documents\\file.txt

Comment: great:) now please accept his answer. click on the arrow and watch it turn green :)

Answer (score 2):

If its windows, it should be:

```
  String path="C:\\My documents\\file.txt";
```